# entities cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, proxy, one-to-many

I do have an error trying to get datas into a proxy which should contains its own datas and some others coming from another proxy. ( Many To One Relation )

In my example, product proxy gets its own datas but it seems to be unable to get the Manufacturer proxy.
All i done is to add a getter and a setter in product proxy:

```
ManufacturerProxy getManufacturer ();
void setManufacturer (ManufacturerProxy manufacturer);
```

Sounds like something is missing. Can someone help me on this ?

Regards,

pierre

```
com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: Server Error: org.nit.persistance.entites.Manufacturer_$$_javassist_3 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$StandardPayloadDialect.processPayload(AbstractRequestContext.java:414)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$5.onTransportSuccess(AbstractRequestContext.java:1151)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.gwt.client.DefaultRequestTransport$1.onResponseReceived(DefaultRequestTransport.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:258)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:412)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor127.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor45.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: This is the client-side view from a server-side error. You'll need to get at the server-side error for details. Set a breakpoint in [`DefaultExceptionHandler`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/server/DefaultExceptionHandler.html) to get the server-side stack-trace.

Comment: I had the same issue. It was solved by removing the LazyLoading on the getter. I didn't noticed any performance issue because I guess because it's a One relationship

Comment: Tks thomas for your help. Indeed, it was a server side error. Will open another thread to get some help on how to solve it. Thanks for your time